# Sharepoint 2013- Lists with fields that show up on conditions?

Tags: 2013, list

Is it possible to make a list that tailors the information entered based on the choices made within the list?

For example:

Only show field2 for the user to enter information if field1 has "Yes" selected.

or

Only show field4 for the user to enter a date if field3 has "Choice 2" checkmarked.

I've looked all over, but can't find anything of the sort. Perhaps I'm not using a key phrase or term that will direct me to the right answer.

I currently don't have access to Sharepoint Designer, and only the web layout to create and add apps. But I may be able to get access to Designer if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can show and hide theses fields on demand based on your `choice field selected value` via Jquery without using SharePoint Designer by doing the following :

- Open your new form via the browser.
- Edit Page .

[image]

- Add web Part > Add Script Editor .

[image]

Add the following code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
//Show/hide columns based on Choice Field Selection
$("select[title='Field1']").change(function() {
if ($("select[title='Field1']").val() != "Yes")
{
$('nobr:contains("Field2")').closest('tr').hide();
}
else
{
$('nobr:contains("Field2")').closest('tr').show();
}
});
});

</script>
```

Now when you **do not select** `Yes` from `Field1` that is Choice field it should hide `Field2` and if select `Yes` it should show `Field2`

For step by step guide for New/ Edit / Display Form  [check Show / Hide fields based on choice field selection using JQuery in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/19/show-hide-fields-based-on-choice-field-selection-using-jquery-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: what's your fields name ?

Comment: Dear TTRC , don't worry I am here to help you so please provide me with your current code  to check it on my side

Comment: I got it working! :)